# Solr 3.1 doesn't index the file

Tags: solr, indexing, solrnet, apache-tika

I have configured Solr 3.1 with Apache tika 0.9 successfully
I don't change Schema.xml(default schema) and solrconfig.xml file

I have pass this command to browser :

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=post1&commit=true%20-F%20%22myfile=@D:\code.txt%22
```

Output :

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">593</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

But whenever i search from http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/  with *:* , it's doesn't give any record

please help me on that ASAP

Thanks
Dhaval,

Answer (score 0):

I think the *myfile=@d:\code.txt* syntax is only understood by the command line utility *curl*. Most browsers won't support it.

Retry it with curl, and I think it should work for you. Then look at further solr examples for how to do the post with a browser if you really need to.